# configuring kerberose-sso-negotiate in multiple domains

Tags: dns, kerberos, negotiate

I have mycorp.com, ch1.mycorp.com, mycorp2.com domains (it is all windows)
I am configuring sso-kerberose-negotiate authentication
My server running in mainaaa3.mycorp2.com, I have created spn "http:/mainaaa3.mycorp2.com" for it, and I have set trusts between domains, 
but if users from mycorp.com, ch1.mycorp.com domains that browser do not send negotiate-ticket, and then I have created spn in each domains for "http:/mainaaa3.mycorp2.com", and now I have error:
      Mechanism level: Integrity check on decrypted field failed (31)

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The SPN shouldn't have a semi colon in it, you should have "http/mainaaa3.mycorp2.com". That may not be your only problem, however.

You should ask this question on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) instead, as it is not directly related to programming.